# What does mean reputation in personal data?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history

When a screen with personal data is opened then there is a row with titles

```
"summary ....reputation..."
```

And the score shown for this reputation differs from the reputation that is shown with your nickname in answers or questions.

For example my score of the reputation in this row is 74. What does this magic number mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are referring to. Could you please provide a screenshot please?

Comment: @ProgramFOX  I mean the row in the right bottom corner of personal data in stackoverf;pw.

Comment: are you asking about [meta-tag:reputation-history] in [meta-tag:profile-page]?

Comment: @gnat  There was answered the question already. The answer contains the image of the reputation I spoke.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about this number:

> [image: Reputation Tab]

It is merely an indication of how much reputation you've earned *since the last time you visited that tab*, so you know that there have been new changes. It resets back to zero once you've viewed the tab again.

Comment: .. similar to two or three others in that tab *and* the top bar notifications for rep changes, comments and winter bash hats.